# How to keep get responses from the server? (PHP,JS,HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
<!--index.html-->
<script>
  function work()
  {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "doWork.php");
    ajax.send("doIt");           
  }
</script>
<button onClick="work();" />
```

,

```
<!--doWork.php-->
<?php
  echo "Loading...";
  hardWork1(); // or maybe sleep(10);
  echo "Completed number xxx";
?>
```

Hi, I want to get two messages or more in sequence from the server.

Like above code, such as "Loading..." before "Completed Number xxx".

Do I have to add another AJAX send in first AJAX's callback?

Comment: WebSockets would be the professional solution, other than that, keep doing AJAX requests every second or so and write only one status update per request

Comment: That's great, but looks like too professional. But I'll keep look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```html
<div id="content">
Loading...
</div>
```

```js
…
if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
    document.getElementById().innerHTML = 'Completed Number ' + ajax.responseText;
}
…
```

Comment: Simply yes, but what if status are more. Do I have to make another send?? Status keep changes, after completed once. like level 1...2...3...4..

Comment: You can put your "status code" at the beggining of the response and then get it from the response like this:

`var response = ajax.responseText;
if (response.charAt(0)) === '5'
 alert('Error 5!');
response.substr(1); //remove first character`

Comment: Sorry, I think I've made wrong question. Problem is responses are comes together at same time.